# Regex for Number and Decimal and Percentage in one textbox

Tags: regex

Can someone help me provide the Regex for the following numbers?
I can have either numeric or decimal or numeric in percentage.

`100` or `50.15` or `75%`.

I tried for the `\d*(\.)?\d*(%)` regex but it's only working for the percentage.
The `\d*(\.)\d*` one is numeric or decimal but I couldn't figure out how to combine both.

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex `/^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$/`

- `^` should start with
- `\d+` atleast one digit (sure and more)
- `(\.\d+)?` may or may not contain decimal part
- `%?` may or may not contain `%` symbol
- `$` end

```js
var re=/^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$/;

console.log(re.test('123')); // true
console.log(re.test('123.32'));  // true
console.log(re.test('123.32%')); // true
console.log(re.test('123%'));  // true
console.log(re.test('123.')); // false  . atlast
console.log(re.test('123.%')); // false .% atlast
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you attempted to solve your problem first and then ask for help if you have difficulty otherwise how will you learn?

The following site is good for testing regex: http://regexr.com/

That being said, the following should work:

```
/^\d+\.?\d*\%?$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
^\d+$|^\d+\.\d+$|^\d+%$
```

Explanation:

- `^\d+$` only numeric

or

- `^\d+\.\d+$`  decimal value

or

- `^\d+%$` only numeric with percentage

[regx demo](https://regex101.com/r/JpiHYi/5)

Comment: I don't know if OP would like it, but your regex won't catch decimal percentage  like 12.34%

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*%?
```

This will do the job

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @DimaSan It's ok, I will be careful about it for my next answers. I didn't think about other people who will come afterwards.